# Nuxt 3 re-fetch session on the client

Tags: typescript, session, nuxt.js, keycloak, refresh-token

I am using [nuxt-auth-utils](https://github.com/Atinux/nuxt-auth-utils) with Keycloak with SSR enabled. I update the tokens stored in session when refreshing them is necessary. It happens on the server-side and on the client side they stay the same. When I reload the page, client gets the updated values, but when navigating, it doesn't.

Is it possible to get the modified session on the client side without reloading?

I have the updated tokens in `json` and this is how I update session:

```js
await setUserSession(event, {
  access_token: json.access_token,
  access_token_expires_in: json.expires_in,
  refresh_token: json.refresh_token,
  refresh_token_expires_in: json.refresh_expires_in
})
```

On the client this is how I access the session:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { session } = useUserSession()
const { access_token, refresh_token } = session.value
</script>
<template>
    <pre>{{ access_token }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ refresh_token }}</pre>
</template>
```

Comment: Turns out `useUserSession()` has a method called `fetch` and it does exactly what I need.